# USB-C PD, Voltage and Current of Power Adaptors

Tags: voltage, current, usb, battery-charging, usb-c

I have a rather basic question... but I don't want to take chances.

I have two MacBook Pros, one which ships with a 87W power unit, and the other a 96W power unit.

Now, I understand that a device won't draw more current than needed. I also believe I understand that voltages are negotiated and that using too high a voltage is dangerous.

Furthermore, I expect that USB-C, as a 'smart tech' should be more controlled than just hooking up 'raw' electricity to a device.

That said...

*When I inspect my 96W charger I see:*

```
Output Voltage: 20.5VDC/4.7A or 15VDC/3A or 9VDC/3A or 5.2VDC/3A
```

*When I inspect my 87W charger I see:*

```
Output Voltage: 20.2V/4.3A, 9V/3A, 5.2V/2.4A.
```

I don't see a **clean voltage match for my 96W Mac vs my 87W Mac, there is at least a .3v difference**

Is this safe to interchange these devices?

If so, what's insulating me (pun intended), the small voltage difference... or the smarts of USB-C PD?

Comment: Any well build product that is designed to take in 20V from an outside source will not care if the voltage is 20.2V or 20.5V. It is probably rated to something much higher, and on top of that it likely has some sort of over-voltage protection.

Even if an adapter is spec'd to output 20V, the actual voltage will always vary a bit depending on how much current is being drawn (and if that current changes quickly, the voltage will spike/sag accordingly).

Comment: Also, both chargers seem to support 9V at 3A and 5.2V at at least 2.4A, so even if the power delivery negotiation deems the 20.5V too high (it definitely won't though), it can fall back to either of those. Though it'll charge slower at the lower voltage.

Comment: thanks folks... happy to mark as correct if you wish to add as answer. By the way more generally, All USB-C should be completely interchangeable without issue right?

Comment: what is `All USB-C`? ...  do you mean all USB-C capable devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small voltage difference is inconsequential for this kind of high power application. At least the power consumer should be aware of this difference, since all source parameters are clearly communicated to consumer over Power Delivery messaging protocol. The producer-consumer have an option to negotiate the best (optimal) power contract. If for some goofy reason the consumer doesn't like the extra 300 mV, it will reject the contract and negotiate another, close enoigh. So to answer your main question whether it is safe to interchange the supply bricks, then yes, it is safe.

Comment: Thanks, one last thing, if a lower wattage is negotiated than the device needs due to running at high CPU usage, will this be damaging to the battery or will it just drain slower?

Comment: @Woodstock, modern PD can negotiate variable voltages, not only the ones shown on AC-DC brick, so I don't know if this is your case. However, if lower power profile gets negotiated, usually it will only re-balance the battery charging function. When working at high CPU usage, the system will slow the battery charge. But it all depends on quality of laptop implementation, it may also throttle down the CPU.